# What skills introduced prior to the formal introduction of Haki are Busoshoku Haki based?

Tags: one-piece

There are 6 techniques that are the keys to Rokushiki.  Despite a claim in another [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9987/how-can-cp9-members-and-sanji-run-in-the-air/9991#9991) from a well informed user that none of the CP9 members are haki users, several of these techniques seem to be rudimentary forms of Busoshoku Haki.  It seems completely reasonable that the marines would be training them in the use of Haki based skills.

In particular: Tekkai, Rokuogan, and Shigan seem to clearly be Haki based.  There are, however, some points against this including Luffy's reaction to Shigan.

Geppo and Rankyaku could feasibly be viewed as imparting ones willpower/Haki to the air like a projectile.

Only Soru does not seem to fit this but Sanji's simular technique (Blue Walk) was (at least partially) transfered to Nami when his mind was transfered.  By [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11351/what-all-abilities-are-transferred-when-hearts-are-interchanged-between-bodies) answer Haki is transferred but not physical strength.

There are several other techniques that, if these are Haki based, would also need to be Haki based such as Sanji's Sky and Blue walks and Zorro's ranged sword attacks.

Finally we address swordsmen. Not covered by the CP9's skill but still seems to be early stages of learning Haki is Zorro's cutting of steel.  His sword would normally not be able to cut something as hard or harder than itself but he learns to impart his willpower to it to make it cut what and only what he wants it to.  This is complemented by an early use of observation haki immediately prior to it in his fight against Mr. 1.

My one question is therefore: **Are there any abilities that were shown prior to the introduction of haki on the show (such as the potential examples above) that have either been shown to work by using Busoshoku Haki (knowingly or not) after it's introduction or have been confirmed by canon sources to be Haki?**

As I consider it Haki was introduced on Amazon Lily and in the several instances that were observed on the archipelago. The nature of this question invites speculation as I've done above but I would prefer justification in canon.  I understand anime physics don't have to be realistic but this would explain alot.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand your question here, are you asking about what haki abilities that have been shown before the introduction of haki or after?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Whether any bushido haki was shown before the archepelago arc where they feature it extensively to be explained partially on amazon lily. Not nessesarily connected to Rokushiki but that was listed as a case where we might have possibly seen it due to inherent simularilites between the abilities.

Comment: I don't think it was, apart from Garp hitting Luffy.

Comment: @PeterRaeves that's not haki, Oda said himself

Comment: Out of universe lore aside: We see Zorro use his (low-)ranged slash attack in the Punk Hazard arc when he cuts the snow-harpy in half. She is clearly shocked about the fact that she is still alive since **had Zorro used Haki**, her logia fruit **would not have saved her**. They are even talking about this afterwards and Zorro explains why he **did not use Haki** against her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first use your examples to explain Rokushiki and Haki and then give a comparative conclusion using the wiki.

## Rokushiki

Rokushiki was mainly explained in chapter 348 and was explained to be pure body strength with every technique. Rob Lucci confirms this after the CP9 had defeated the Strawhats for the first time.

- Tekkai

  > Our **bodies** are trained to the point of mimicking an iron shell.
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Soru

  > It only seems as though I've disappeared. With the **explosive power of my legs**...
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Geppo (See also [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9987/6166)

  > (Also with the **explosive power of my legs**) I can kick the air and float...
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Rankyaku

  > Nami: They cut the wall with their kicks!?
  >   Kalifa: If you have the **speed** to create a kamakaze, then it's possible...
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Overall

  > We've trained our **bodies** to great extremes since we were young.
  >   [image: enter image description here!]

## Strawhat crew's attacks

- Sanji's sky and blue walk are basically like Geppo. The more power you gain in your legs, the faster you can move. So if you master this technique anyone could do it, as we have seen Sanji do in Nami's body. This could be argued to only have been possible by Sanji somehow imbuing Haki into Nami's legs as she would not have been as powerful to use blue walk. That's why I mentioned that technique is needed also. After being a thief and being on the run for most of her teen years, Nami has the physical potential of using blue and maybe even sky walk, she just didn't learn the technique needed to do so.
- Zoro's ranged attacks are basically like Rankyaku. The more speed you can put in your slashes, the bigger the slash gets. Haki can be imbued to make the slash stronger as Law did against Vergo or when Mihawk slashed at Whitebeard (the fact whether Haki was imbued here, is debatable though). Haki can be imbued, but it isn't needed to create ranged slashes as explained with Rankyaku. Mere arm power or slash techniques would be enough.
- Zoro cutting steel aka Mr.1
  As explained in the following question, [Zoro did not use haki in Alabasta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13306/6166)

## Haki

Haki on the other hand is a pure mental power and it might not even be possible to get it out even with enormous training.

- Overall

  > Haki is a power that **lies dormant** in all the world's creatures, but a majority of humans go without noticing this power or perhaps finish their lives failing to ever pull it out, **even if they try**...
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Kenbunshoku Haki

  > The ability to **sense** the opponent's presence even more strongly is haki with the color of observation.
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Busoshoku Haki

  > This power can also be imbued into weapons (and can thus not be a mere physical trait as you can't *train* weapons)
  >   [image: enter image description here!]
- Haoshoku Haki

  > This color of the conquerer however, **cannot be trained and strengthened**, even if you are able to control it.
  >   [image: enter image description here!]

## Difference

Therefore to conclude, Rokushiki is not Haki. **The result might be similar, but they are fundamentally different.** **Rokushiki is based on pure physical power, while Haki is based on will power.** You could therefore technically have both Rokushiki Tekkai enhancement and Busoshuoku Haki at the same time, although this has not been shown in the series thus far. This is also why Rokushiki can be easily taught by becoming physically stronger, while Haki must be developed by becoming mentally stronger, which isn't as easy to do. Rokushiki will therefore not make the user able to negate Devil Fruit powers and hit Logia users for example.

> Tekkai is similar to Busoshoku Haki, as both reinforce the users body in some way, the difference being that Haki is based on the user's willpower and Tekkai is based on the user's physical power. Also, Tekkai is more inclined to defense and the user exhibits no movement while it is active. In comparison, Busoshoku Haki is capable of both offense and defense.

[Source on Tekkai](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Rokushiki/Tekkai)

---

## Other information

If you want to read more about Haki, see the question about [the abilities that are transferred when hearts are interchanged between bodies](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11358/6166)
If you want to read more about Geppo, see the question about [how CP9 members and Sanji can run in the air](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9987/6166)

## Usage

**Background**

> It was used by **Garp** for the first time against Luffy to bypass his Devil Fruit power and hurt him in Water 7. Later, **Sentomaru** used a Haki-imbued attack against Luffy, which made the Straw Hats think he was a Devil Fruit user due to their lack of knowledge about the ability. Afterwards, **Rayleigh** used Haki to stop Kizaru and even touch his Logia body. The first time the **Kujas** named this ability "Haki", they were shown wielding Haki-imbued arrows. During the **Marineford War**, Haki was also used many times by marines and pirates alike. It was shown that Haki is very common in the New World, unlike in Paradise where Haki users are fairly rare and almost nobody knows about it. It is later explained by Rayleigh once he begins training Luffy.

**Examples**

> - **It can be used to augment the user's own attacks**, projected ahead of the user as pure brute force, or imbued in weapons to increase their effectiveness. Any attack enhanced by Busoshoku Haki hits immensely harder than it would normally be without it. The Kuja's Haki-imbued arrows, for example, are capable of penetrating solid stone.
> - **This type of Haki also has the ability to bypass the powers of a Devil Fruit user**, touching the "substantial body" beneath whatever protection the fruit provides, such as the case of body-altering Devil Fruits such as Logia or Paramecia users. However, unlike Kairoseki, it does not negate a user's Devil Fruit powers, allowing them to defend themselves, and continue fighting normally. By the same effect, this Haki can also be used as a higher level of offensive, more so than just bypassing a foe's Devil Fruit powers.
> - **A heavy concentration (or coating) of this Haki can be used to harden parts of one's body**, turning the area black, thus making the user denser and more formidable, and giving their attacks greater power. Although Luffy, the first in the mainstream storyline to demonstrate this effect, named the technique as Busoshoku: Koka (武装色 硬化 Busō-shoku: Kōka?, Color of Armaments: Hardening), no other users except Donquixote Doflamingo, such as Vergo and Smoker referred to this method by such a name.
> - **Busoshoku Haki works independently of the user's Devil Fruit**, as shown when Luffy uses it to enhance his Gear Third attack underwater. This type of Haki may not be equipped to attacks that are not from one's body except for weapons, or anything generated from one's own body (like Kizaru's laser beams, Marco's flames or any other energy/non-solid attacks based on Devil Fruits). So, those who attack with parts of their body can combine their Haki and Devil Fruit powers.

[Source on Busoshoku Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Busoshoku_Haki)

Comment: I don't consider the wiki a Canon source as I could edit it now to say it is haki.  That doesn't, however, mean you are wrong (which is why I asked). Vergo may be your combined haki and Rokushiki user at the same time but it isnt stated. I remember his shigan turning black but need to find that.

Comment: Ah! His shigan being black may have been his gloves in the manga as I cant find an image from the anime.

Comment: @kaine I just checked, but at the time Vergo attacked G5 it looked like he was wearing black gloves. So it's hard to tell whether he used Haki. I doubt he did, because he wouldn't really need it against fodder.

Comment: @kaine He is wearing gloves, check this out. http://i.stack.imgur.com/wsMOp.png

Comment: TL;DR: "**Garp** for the first time against Luffy to bypass his Devil Fruit power and hurt him in Water 7. Later, **Sentomaru** used a Haki-imbued attack against Luffy, which made the Straw Hats think he was a Devil Fruit user due to their lack of knowledge about the ability. Afterwards, **Rayleigh** used Haki to stop Kizaru and even touch his Logia body. The first time the **Kujas** named this ability "Haki", they were shown wielding Haki-imbued arrows. During the **Marineford War**, Haki was also used many times by marines and pirates alike." -- for Busoshoku Haki

Comment: @DazC i know this answer has gotten way too long but did u just copy random text from the answer? The real tl;dr is "haki is will power. Rokushiki is physical power". Maybe i should start adding tl;dr's to my answers.

Comment: The question asks for prior skills/abilities so I picked out prior instances/displays (Garp's punch, Sentomaru's push, Rayleigh's kick, Kuja's arrows, war soldier's war soldiering) from Paradise.

Comment: @DazC I guess all prior busoshoku haki usage was all remembered when rayleigh explained haki to luffy. Basically all those u said. I should really revise this answer some time in the future.