# Was the first time Zoro experienced haki in Alabasta?

Tags: one-piece

Remember when Zoro learned to cut steel in Alabasta and he heard the breath in all things?  Was this swordsmanship or was this his first encounter with Haki?

[image]

Comment: nothing ever said that it was haki AFAIK, it's just swordsmanship skill from Zorro, his teacher told him about it.

Comment: It's hard to say and maybe just based on opinions... hear the breath of all things could be haki. but to cut steel could also be cause Zoro is such a strong. @ShinobuOshino do you have the link from his teacher?

Comment: @BBallBoy no, but I remember that, it was in chapter 194 Slashing Through Metal. And in chapter 195 Zorro explain that he was hearing their "breath"

Comment: Just want to also point out when he heard the breath in all things it let him automatically dodge all the falling debris which is very Mantra like.  Also Mantra was introduced in the next Arc.

Comment: There has been no confirmation that ive been able to find that says for sure if these abilities are connected to haki or not.  I asked on here specifically about whether any examples of armor haki were shown earlier on and got no confirmed examples. Ive searched and dont think I or anyone else here has a be all end all answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's not Haki, but it's similar to Haki. When he heard the rock falling, he did not dodge them, but instead he knew where the rock were gonna fall. Kenbunshoku Haki has something similar, but the user predicts an opponent's moves which makes it much easier for them to evade the attack given enough skill. Zorro was also able to sense where his sword was, while no Haki users are known to have this ability.

Zorro didn't move and he said he was not evading those rock

[image]

Haki users can evade attacks.

[image]

> Though the power allows the user to predict most attacks, it can be circumvented by various means. It cannot predict inherently random attacks; for example, Luffy managed to bypass Enel's Mantra by bouncing his fists off a nearby wall, to prevent himself and thus Enel from knowing where they would land. [(source)](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Kenbunshoku_Haki#Drawbacks)

So it was clear that Haki users can't use their Haki power to predict a movement that was not intended. Therefore, Zorro's ability to sense those rocks was not Haki.

Another proof that Zorro couldn't use Haki at that time is that he was able to cut through Daz Bone's metal (which is actually possible with enough skill), but he couldn't cut through Enel's lighting (impossible without using Busoshoku Haki).

Comment: Zoro can't use Haki. I think you should specify time.

Comment: Also the problem with stating he can't use haki at Alabasta because he couldn't cut Enel would be there were several incidents where luffy used haki unknowingly then wasn't able to use it later until he was taught.  Same thing happened to Ace when he was little. The luffy dodging Enel thing makes sense though to your point.

Comment: @Quikstryke Haki is a mysterious power that is found in every living being in the world. Zorro has it, Luffy has it, Ace has it, but they can't use it at that time, they need to train their haki first.

Comment: Personally believe its a mistake to treat using raw untrained haki once or under certain specific situations  means you can control it. Why would he think cuttimg lightning is like cutting steel? The sword, however, is a good point. And Oda doesnt really need to connect it to haki so wont.

Comment: @kaine what I was trying to say is Zorro didn't cut Daz Bone's devil fruit, but actually cut his metal body and ignoring that it's actually devil fruit power.

Comment: I understood that. There is no way in real life that one can cut a chunk of steel armor that is as strong as the blade without ruining the blade. You said he did this with a unrealistic (as one piece usually is) skill and posted a counter arguement to it being haki. My statement was a counter arguement to that arguement though you are likely correct.

Comment: I think you are right he did actually cut steel without haki, but I was more interested in the hearing inanimate objects part, but your post makes sense.  I guess what prompted me to ask this question was Roger's was called the man able to hear the voices of all things.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that makes sense to me is that; Zorro is using both kinds of Haki in tandem.

One, he can sense his Iwashimizu sword which in itself is special as due to its rarity and nature, + the swords in *One Piece* have unexplored depths e.g. black swords, and cursed swords. Hence, the ability to sense it with Haki as it is probably imbued with another's spirit.

Two, knowing the breath of things as it is stated, maybe how Zorro utilises his Haki, in this event he knows the breath of steel, so he strengthens his own steel with Haki just enough to cut Das Bonez.